# How to programmatically set directory for hadoop *-site.xml's

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration-files

My java application should define folder for hadoop xmls in runtime (let it taken from program command line argument for simplicity). I guess, I can use something like following code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()

....

Configuration = new Configuration
config.addResource(new Path(String.format("%s/core-site.xml", hadoopLocation)));
config.addResource(new Path(String.format("%s/hdfs-site.xml", hadoopLocation)));
config.addResource(new Path(String.format("%s/tez-site.xml", hadoopLocation)));
config.addResource(new Path(String.format("%s/yarn-site.xml", hadoopLocation)));
config.addResource(new Path(String.format("%s/mapred-site.xml", hadoopLocation)));
config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName() );
config.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName() );

try {
    FileSystem dfs = FileSystem.get(config);
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Failed to process hadoop file system");
}
```

However, I should repeat it with each call `new Configuration()` in my program or use some persistent preconfigured `baseConfiguration` object and use it like `new Configuration(baseConfiguration)`. All of these ways looks pretty clumsy. Is there more elegant solution. Maybe something like static method call I can perform once. The following code is presented for illustration only:

```
Configuration.setBaseXmlsDir();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop application looks for these files inside classpath. If you run `hadoop classpath` you should be able to see the configuration directory on the list.

So, to modify location you just need to modify classpath before application runs. The easiest way is to define environment variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` before starting the application like this:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/your/path/to/xmls
hadoop jar ...
```